# ffmpeg output to multiple files simultaneously

Tags: ffmpeg

What format/syntax is needed for ffmpeg to output the same input to several different "output" files? For instance different formats/different bitrates?  Does it support parallelism on the output?

Answer (score 5):

From [FFMpeg documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html), FFmpeg *writes to an arbitrary number of output "files"*.

Just make sure each output file (or stream), is preceded by the proper output options.

Comment: What about multiple stream input and ofcourse multiple output?

Answer (score 5):

I use

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -re -i 'life=s=300x200:mold=10:r=25:ratio=0.1:death_color=#C83232:life_color=#00ff00,scale=1200:800:flags=16' \
-f lavfi -re -i sine=frequency=1000:sample_rate=44100 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-c:v libx264 -b:v 1000k -g 30 -keyint_min 60 -profile:v baseline -preset veryfast -c:a aac -b:a 96k  \
-f flv "rtmp://yourname.com:1935/live/stream1" \
-f flv "rtmp://yourname.com:1935/live/stream2" \
-f flv "rtmp://yourname.com:1935/live/stream3" \
```

Comment: Use the [tee muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee) so you only have to encode once, not three times.

Answer (score 3):

Is there any reason you can't just run more than one instance of `ffmpeg`? I've have great results with that ...

Generally what I've done is run `ffmpeg` once on the **source** file to get it to sort of the base standard (say a higher quality h.264 mp4 file) this will make sure your other jobs will run more quickly if your **source** file has any issues since they'll be cleaned up in this first pass

Then use that new **source/input** file to run x number of `ffmpeg` jobs, for example in **bash** ...

*Where you see "..." would be where you'd put all your encoding options.*

```
# create 'base' file

ffmpeg -loglevel error -er 4 -i $INPUT_FILE ... INPUT.mp4 >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1

# the command above will run and then move to start 3 background jobs
# text output will be sent to a log file

echo "base file done!"

# note & at the end to send job to the background

ffmpeg ... -i INPUT.mp4 ... FILENAME1.mp4 ... >/dev/null 2>&1 &
ffmpeg ... -i INPUT.mp4 ... FILENAME2.mp4 ... >/dev/null 2>&1 &
ffmpeg ... -i INPUT.mp4 ... FILENAME3.mp4 ... >/dev/null 2>&1 &

# wait until you have no more background jobs running

wait > 0
echo "done!"
```

Each of the background jobs will run in parallel and will be (essentially) balanced over your cpus, so you can maximize each core.

Comment: Yeah you could, though it's said to "save cpu" if you use one input process (http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/Multiple-output-files-td2076623.html) and sometimes it isn't possible, for example in live streaming...

Comment: I'm messing around with reading `/dev/video0` and the second `ffmpeg` complains that the device is busy.

Answer (score 2):

based on http://sonnati.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/ffmpeg-–-the-swiss-army-knife-of-internet-streaming-–-part-iv/ and http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/Multiple-output-files-td2076623.html

```
ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://server/live/high_FMLE_stream -acodec copy -vcodec x264lib -s 640×360 -b 500k -vpre medium -vpre baseline rtmp://server/live/baseline_500k -acodec copy -vcodec x264lib -s 480×272 -b 300k -vpre medium -vpre baseline rtmp://server/live/baseline_300k -acodec copy -vcodec x264lib -s 320×200 -b 150k -vpre medium -vpre baseline rtmp://server/live/baseline_150k -acodec libfaac -vn -ab 48k rtmp://server/live/audio_only_AAC_48k
```

Or you could pipe the output to a "tee" and send it to "X" other processes to actually do the encoding, like

ffmpeg -i input - | tee ...

which might save cpu since it might enable more output parallelism, which is apparently otherwise unavailable

see http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs and [here](http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/Multiple-output-files-td2076623.html)

Comment: This is quite outdated. There is no `x264lib` encoder, and `-vpre` has been deprecated a long time ago. `-b` alone is ambiguous and should not be used.

Comment: Yeah http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs has more up to date information than this post did...

Answer (score 1):

I have done like that

```
ffmpeg -re -i nameoffile.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ar 44100 -strict -2 -f flv  \
-f flv rtmp://rtmp.1.com/code \
-f flv rtmp://rtmp.2.com/code \
-f flv rtmp://rtmp.3.com/code \
-f flv rtmp://rtmp.4.com/code \
-f flv rtmp://rtmp.5.com/code \
```

but is not working completely well as i was expecting and having on restream with nginx

Answer (score 0):

Well I used this way. So you take input once, define settings for each output that's it. If you want 3 output files, just add so.

```py
command = (
    # Start of the command string
    f"sudo ffmpeg -i {input_path}/{content_id}.mp4 "
    f"-c:a copy -vf scale=-2:{height} -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -level:v 4.0 "
    f"-x264-params scenecut=0:open_gop=0:min-keyint=72:keyint=72 "
    f"-minrate {bitrate} -maxrate {bitrate} -bufsize {bitrate} -b:v {bitrate} "
    f"-y -preset veryfast -crf 20 -movflags +faststart "
    # First output file path
    f"{output_path1}/{content_id}_{height}p_{bitrate}.mp4 "
    # Second output file path
    f"-y -preset veryfast -crf 20 -movflags +faststart "
    f"{output_path2}/{content_id}_{height}p_{bitrate}.mp4 "
    # Options that are not part of the file paths
    "-loglevel quiet -stats"
    # End of the command string
)
```